# Changing input values from table1 to table2 on keypress mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

see [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L7bnzrz0/2/)

Can anyone guide me on keypress event, I can't get my input values right?

```
$(document).on('keydown', $('#table1 tbody tr td input'), function (e) {
var oldValue ='?';//get the input value before keypress or edit

    var newValue = "?"; //get the input value after keypress or edit

  $('#table2').find('tbody tr').each(function (i) {
        var $td2 = $(this).find('td input:text');
        if (oldValue == $td2.val()){
            $td2.val(newValue);    
        }
    });

});
```

and   `$(document).on('keydown', $('#table1 tbody tr td input'), function (e) {` should only apply on table 1 first column ,right now it also applying when keypress on table1 column 2 is triggered.

Does if I edit "Apple" to "Apple Pie", Apple from table 2 will automatically change to "Apple Pie".

Comment: it is compulsary to do it by each loop we can also do this by using class name

Comment: i am unable to see where you grab input value and trying to put values in second table td's input

Comment: so I dont need to get straigt to put the second loop inside @TheMechanic

Comment: @TheMechanic For example,If I edit "Apple" to "Apple Pie" on upper table, Apple from table2(one Apple text is there) will automatically change to "Apple Pie" on keypresss event

Comment: i understand what you are trying to do. But can we do it by class name or something else? because how can we compare on which input we have to put value?

Comment: Ok ok.can you show me how ? or give me idea?

Comment: @TheMechanic see this http://jsfiddle.net/L7bnzrz0/3/, my problm now is how to get the new inputted value.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L7bnzrz0/4/ This?

Comment: @phillip100 Thanks, had that part solved in different way, but can you also help me, how to get the new value (after edit or keypress) and set it on this part `            $td2.val(newvalue);`

Comment: @TheMechanic have you posted your answer? cant see it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L7bnzrz0/7/ This?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).off('keydown').on('keydown', $('#table1 tbody tr td input'), function (e) {

var oldValue =$(e.target).val();//get the input value before keypress or edit
    $(document).on('keyup', $('#table1 tbody tr td input'),function(e){ 

        $('#table2').find('td input').each(function(){
            if($(this).val() === oldValue){
                $(this).val($(e.target).val());
            }
        $(document).off('keyup');
        });
    });              
});
```

Try this now:

```
 $(document).off('keydown').on('keydown', '#table1 input:first', function (e) {

var oldValue =$(e.target).val();//get the input value before keypress or edit
    $(document).on('keyup', '#table1 input:first',function(e){ 

        $('#table2').find('td input:first').val($(e.target).val());
        $(document).off('keyup');
    });              
});
```

Comment: whatda! I'm closed to hate keyevents and cursed it. can you explain me what happen on that?

Comment: Simply keydown returns oldvalue & keyup return newValue thats it

Comment: Also, this get to happen on every column `$(document).off('keydown').on('keydown', $('#table1 tbody tr td input'), `, I dont know what to add so its happen on first column of tablerow 1 only

Comment: if you want for first column then use indexing for this

Comment: I have done this but n luck, $('#table1 tbody tr td input:eq(0)')

Comment: yes,automatic changing of fields of lower table should happen only on upper table column1 inputs. Right now, If second column of table1 has Apple and was changed,the Apples on lower table also changes.

Comment: ,also see this bug, If I add another input outside the table1, table2 duplicate input fields keeps on changing. http://jsfiddle.net/L7bnzrz0/11/

Comment: I ended up chngng this $(document).off('keydown').on('keydown', $('#table1 tbody tr td input'), to class.

Comment: Take some beer  4 me!! :D

Comment: only apple is working when edit,not on banana inpt. anyways, thanks a lot. I already assign class on input ,so I have like this $(document).off('keydown').on('keydown', '.givenclass', function (e) { var oldValue =$(e.target).val();//get the input value before keypress or edit $(document).on('keyup', .givenclass',function(e){ $('#table2').find('td input:first').val($(e.target).val()); $(document).off('keyup'); }); });

Comment: another issue I encounter, If I paste text using ctrl c and ctrl v, text on input field still change, but If i paste using right click and paste, input field on table 2 does not change. :( Do I need to go with my keypress event or have to use other event like change?

Answer (score 0):

here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7bnzrz0/2/)

here is the snippet for better understand i have changed the event
Reason: if you wish to instant change

**HTML CODE**

```
<form id='form1'>
<table id='table1'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type='text' class="1" value="Apple" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' value="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type='text' class="2" value="Banana" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' value="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>Table2
<table id='table2'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type='text' class="1" value="Apple" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type='text' class="2" value="Banana" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type='text' class="3" value="Banana" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#table1 tbody tr td input', function (e) {
```

var cls = $(this).attr('class');

var oldValue ='?';//get the input value before keypress or edit

var newValue = "?"; //get the input value after keypress or edit

newValue = $(this).val();

```
  $('#table2').find('tbody tr').each(function (i) {

    var targInp = $(this).find('td input.'+cls)//$(this).find('td input:text')hasClass(cls);
    oldValue = $(this).find('td input.'+cls).val();


    console.log('got it', oldValue);


    if (oldValue != newValue){
        targInp.val(newValue);    
    }
  });
```

});